# Why is newtcbtheorem not working while tcbmaketheorem does?

Tags: macros, theorems, tcolorbox

EDIT: It was simply a matter of outdated package versions. On a mac there are those useful commands sudo tlmgr update –self and after that sudo tlmgr update –all.

The following throws the error "undefined control sequence", but when I switch to \tcbmaketheorem instead it works. Whats the matter?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

%\tcbmaketheorem{mytheo}{My Theorem}{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem{mytheo}{My Theorem}{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheo}{}{}
Great theorem with beautiful box.
\end{mytheo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example compiles without error for me. My guess is that you work with an old version of `tcolorbox`. The current version is 2.51 (2013/09/16). You should check your logfile for your version, i.e. a line like `Package: tcolorbox 2013/09/16 version 2.51 text color boxes` for the current version.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a outdated TeX Live version. 
